# Android file explorer for Ubuntu/Unity via USB, no app needed on Android

Tags: android, file-management, usb

Using Ubuntu/Unity, I would like to browse my USB-connected Android device's files.

Requirements:

- No app needed on the Android side (I have [adb](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) installed if that can help)
- Graphical UI
- Ability to put/pull files to the local Ubuntu filesystem, compatible with Nautilus copy/paste or mouse moves
- Free, ideally open source

Thumbnails not needed.
Integration *within* Nautilus is OK if it does not slow down normal usage of Nautilus.

Comment: I'm not sure about the Nautilus part (as I'm not using that). Are recommendations "ignoring" that part acceptable to you?

Comment: @Izzy: Nautilus copy/paste works with many apps even KDE so I guess there is some kind of standard. I guess most apps use this standard, so just recommend and I will try :-)

Comment: Here you go! I almost forgot about what I am using for that, as I rather prefer CLI – but as the basement is a FUSE mount, this should definitely work with Nautilus, as it makes the Android file system available locally. I use *adbfs-rootless* for years already, highly recommend it to all Linux users with Android devices :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sup>As pointed out in my comment on the question, I cannot tell for the "Nautilus" requirement.</sup>

You've explicitly asked for a graphical file explorer – so I will first answer your request literally. For my really recommended solution, see the end of this post :)

---

**[QtADB](http://qtadb.wordpress.com/)** is probably the best known application in this context:

[image: QtADB file manager] [image: QtADB app manager]
<sup>*QtADB* file manager and app manager (source: [QtADB](http://qtadb.wordpress.com/); click images for larger variants)</sup>

It seems to match your requirements:

- **No app needed on the Android side (I have adb installed if that can help):** Check. ADB is required, but no additional app on the device.
- **Graphical UI:** Check, see screenshots above.
- **Ability to put/pull files to the local Ubuntu filesystem:** Check, see first screenshot.
- **compatible with Nautilus copy/paste or mouse moves:** As initially stated, I cannot check this.
- **Free, ideally open source:** Definitely free. And since 2011 [also open source](https://qtadb.wordpress.com/2011/03/08/qtadb-will-be-open-source/).

---

To name an alternative: **[aafm](https://github.com/sole/aafm)** is a very simple Python based file manager for the command-line and GUI:

[image: aafm]
<sup>*aafm* file manager (source: [aafm](https://github.com/sole/aafm); click image to enlarge)</sup>

I've never tried this one, but it should match your listed requirements the same way (license: GPLv3).

---

**But now for my real recommendation.** Interpreting your question as if you'd asked it at [Android.SE](https://android.stackexchange.com/) ("How can I …"), I'd recommend you taking a look at **[adbfs-rootless](https://github.com/spion/adbfs-rootless)** – which I am using happily. This works as a FUSE mount, and thus your Android file system is available everywhere – no need for a separate file manager, should integrate in whatever file manager you're using as if it belonged there. Thus it really meets *all* your requirements:

- **No app needed on the Android side (I have adb installed if that can help):** No app needed on the Android side (I have adb installed if that can help):
- **Graphical UI:** up to you. If you have a graphical file manager, which you do: Check :)
- **Ability to put/pull files to the local Ubuntu filesystem:** Check. Copy as you would do locally :)
- **compatible with Nautilus copy/paste or mouse moves:** If you use Nautilus, I don't see why not :)
- **Free, ideally open source:** *adbfs-rootless* uses the BSD license, so: Check.

You most likely even can configure a Nautilus shortcut to mount/unmount your Android device for easier use.

Comment: adbfs-rootless is wonderful!

Comment: I told you so :) Best solution ever in this context, wouldn't you agree? Unless you want the additional features of *QtADB* that is – but you didn't ask for those :)